# Casting a datatype in Android

Tags: android, oop, inheritance, casting

Resources myResources = getResources();

CharSequence styledText = myResources.getText(R.string.stop_message);
Drawable icon = myResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.app_icon);

int opaqueBlue = myResources.getColor(R.color.opaque_blue);

float borderWidth = myResources.getDemension(R.dimen.standard_border);

Animation tranout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.spin_shrink_fade);

String{} stringArray = myResources.getStringArray(R.array.string_array);

int[] intArray = myResources.getIntArray(R.array.integer_array);

Resources myResources = getResources();
AnimationDrawable rocket = (AnimationDrawable)myResources.getDrawable (R.drawable.frame_by_frame);

I'm comparing the last couple statements with the proceeding ones.  My question is why is AnimationDrawable explicitly cast when in the other examples above no casting is required?

Answer (score 1):

Because `AnimationDrawable` extends `Drawable` (indirectly).

`myResources.getDrawable` returns a type of `Drawable`, which must be cast in order to be assigned to a type of `AnimationDrawable`.

Basically `AnimationDrawable` is indirectectly a type of `Drawable`, which means that `Drawable` variables can point to `Drawable` types and its children types (including `AnimationDrawable`). This doesn't work in reverse, for example, you can't assign a type of `Drawable` to a variable that points to AnimationDrawable in the same way you can't assign a type of `Drawable` to a variable pointing to a `LevelListDrawable` (another type of `Drawable`).

See this page for more info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/DrawableContainer.html

And this page for more general info:
http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-inheritance

Comment: public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        O
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        setContentView(R.layout.main); /** I'm still confused.  So how come you don't need to cast onCreate method with a (HelloAndroid).onCreate if it extends Activity? */

Comment: The logic its seems you guys are laying out is that you explicitly cast when a method which originates in a superclass is used in a derived class.  If so then shouldn't onCreate method which originates in the super Activity class have a cast such as public void (HelloAndroid).onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState);

Comment: Don't even think about when methods are used right now, just worry about basic polymorphism. You are trying to assign an "Drawable" to an "AnimationDrawable" variable. Since there is no guarantee that your "Drawable" object is-an "AnimationDrawble", you must cast it.

Answer (score 0):

because there are lots of kinds of drawbles, depending on what you request you get different types, all inheriting from the generic drawable ancestor.  Unless you only care about the generic Drawable methods and members, you have to know the type of what you're asking for and cast the generic Drawable to that specific type.